Clarification on when to apply the Born Rule in quantum mechanical measurement problems
One of the postulates of quantum mechanics says that if $A$ is an operator corresponding to some observable, with eigenbasis $\{ |a_i\rangle \}_i$, and we measure some state $|\psi\rangle$ to be in eigenstate $|a_k\rangle$, that the new state is given by
$$|\psi'\rangle = \frac{\langle a_k|\psi\rangle|a_k\rangle}{||\langle a_k|\psi\rangle|a_k\rangle ||} $$
My confusion arises when trying to apply this to sequential measurement problems. For example, if we had a state $|\psi\rangle$ and we measured an observable $A$, getting $a_k$, then an observable $B$ immediately after, which has eigenbasis $\{|b_i\rangle \}_i$, and we wanted to know the probability of getting eigenvalue $b_j$. Then according to this rule, I would expect the probability to be
$$ P_{b_j} = \frac{|| |b_j\rangle\langle b_j|a_k\rangle\langle a_k|\psi\rangle ||^2}{||\langle a_k|\psi\rangle|a_k\rangle ||} = \frac{|\langle b_j|a_k\rangle\langle a_k|\psi\rangle|^2}{|\langle a_k|\psi\rangle|} $$
That said, I am not sure this is correct. For instance, suppose the state is given by $|\psi\rangle = \frac{6}{10}|a_1\rangle+\frac{8}{10}|a_2\rangle$, and the state $|b_1\rangle = \frac{8}{10}|a_1\rangle-\frac{6}{10}|a_2\rangle$. We note that $|\psi\rangle$ and $|b_1\rangle$ are normalized. Suppose a measurement is made of $A$ and we get back $a_1$, and we want to know the probability of getting back $b_1$ when we measure $B$ after $A$. Applying the Born rule,
$$P_{b_1} = \frac{|\langle b_1|a_1\rangle\langle a_1|\psi\rangle|^2}{|\langle a_1|\psi\rangle|} = \frac{|(8/10)(6/10)|^2}{6/10} = \frac{48^2}{100^2}\frac{10}{6} = \frac{48}{125}$$
I am pretty sure this is incorrect. I am wondering if there is just some subtlety that I am missing that implies I can just calculate the probability as $|\langle b_1|a_1\rangle|^2=\frac{64}{100}$. Perhaps because it said that the state is already measured to be $a_1$, so we can 'forget' about the earlier state of $|\psi\rangle$ since it is already measured in this new state? Nevertheless, I am still confused why the Born rule isn't working here, because in some other problems with sequential measurement, I've seen it used.

When you work with normalized states, the probabilities are not supposed to have additional factors in the denominators to normalize them again.

You can simplify notation by assuming that the states $|\psi\rangle$, $|a_i\rangle$, and $|b_j\rangle$ are all normalized. So, suppose without loss of generality that
$$
\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = \langle a_i | a_i \rangle = \langle b_j | b_j \rangle = 1
$$
Then, the probability of measuring eigenvalue $a_i$ after measurement $1$ given that the initial state was $\psi$ is
$$
\mathbb{P}(a_i | \psi) = \left|\langle a_i | \psi \rangle \right|^2
$$
and the state after this measurement is $|a_i\rangle$. After this measurement is made, the probability of measuring $b_j$ given that $a_i$ was seen in measurement $1$ is
$$
\mathbb{P}(b_j | a_i) = \left| \langle b_j | a_i \rangle \right|^2
$$
and after this the state is $|b_j\rangle$.
If you want the probability of measuring $a_i$ and then $b_j$ given that the initial state was $\psi$, the probability is
$$
\mathbb{P}(a_i, b_j | \psi) = \mathbb{P}(b_j | a_i)\mathbb{P}(a_i | \psi) = \left| \langle b_j | a_i \rangle \right|^2 \left|\langle a_i | \psi \rangle \right|^2 
$$

If for some reason you want expressions without assuming normalized states, then you replace a state $|\phi\rangle$ by $\frac{|\phi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \phi | \phi \rangle}}$. So the formulas above become
$$
\mathbb{P}(a_i | \psi) = \frac{\left|\langle a_i | \psi \rangle \right|^2}{\langle a_i | a_i \rangle \langle \psi | \psi \rangle }
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}(b_j | a_i) = \frac{\left|\langle b_j | a_i \rangle \right|^2}{\langle b_j | b_j \rangle \langle a_i| a_i \rangle }
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}(a_i, b_j | \psi) = \frac{\left|\langle b_j | a_i \rangle\right|^2 \left|\langle a_i | \psi \rangle \right|^2}{\langle b_j | b_j \rangle \langle a_i| a_i \rangle^2 \langle \psi | \psi \rangle }
$$
and of course reduce to the ones we have above if the states are normalized.

In general the right way to deal with cases in which you don't understand what is happening in a quantum measurement is to use quantum theory to work it out, not to use a collapse rule.
Suppose you have a system $S$ in the state
$$|\psi\rangle_S=\sum_i\alpha_i|a_i\rangle_S$$
How do you describe a measurement? A measurement produces a record of some physical quantity of the measured system, so it's a coupling between the measurement device $M1$ and the measured system. If you're doing a perfect measurement of an observable $\hat{A}$ with eigenstates $|a_i\rangle$, then the measurement interaction does the following:
$$|a_i\rangle_S|m_0\rangle_{M1}\to|a_i\rangle_S|m_i\rangle_{M1}$$
where the $|m_i\rangle_{M1}$ are some set of orthonormal states of the measurement device. So the measurement produces the motion
$$|\Psi(t_0)\rangle=|\psi\rangle_S|m_0\rangle_{M1}\to|\Psi(t_1)\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i|a_i\rangle_S|m_i\rangle_{M1}$$
If you want to immediately measure some other observable $\hat{B}$ of $S$ with eigenstates $|b_j\rangle$ such that $|a_i\rangle=\sum_j\beta_{ij}|b_j\rangle$ onto a new measurement device $M2$ you apply the relevant motion to $|\Psi(t_1)\rangle$:
$$|\Psi(t_1)\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i|a_i\rangle_S|m_i\rangle_{M1}|m_0\rangle_{M2}\to|\Psi(t_2)\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i\beta_{ij}|b_j\rangle_S|m_i\rangle_{M1}|m_j\rangle_{M2}$$
If you get the $i,j$th outcome the probability for that relative state is $\sum\alpha_i\beta_{ij}$. Since you've applied quantum theory fully instead of using a rule of thumb and you've worked with normalized sets of states you don't have to worry about normalization.
You can introduce various kinds of complications into the above scenario, such as measurement outcomes with non-orthogonal states. Real measurements are in general messier than what I've described above as explained in the literature on decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
As the situations you work with becomes more realistic the collapse rule becomes more misleading because quantum interference may not be entirely suppressed in realistic measurements.
